# How do I set up a one layer custom tile in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and I have a large image which I have been attempting to break up into tiles and save them using the correct filenames so that they can be displayed using Leaflet's tileLayer.  I am trying to keep it simple first by breaking up the large image into just one layer of tiles.  But I have not been able to get Leaflet to load the tiles correctly.  Can anyone show me how a one layer custom tile should be set up in Leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

When your map is not georeferenced, you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) first for georeferencing it.

Now you can use [gdal2tiles.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) to create the tiles for your image. As a result you get a folder with all tiles from your image. gdal2tiles can be installed e.g. through the [OSGeo4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

Now you can add this folder to your map with only some code lines:

```
L.tileLayer('./folder/path/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{ 
  tms:true
}).addTo(map);
```

If there is no need to use "real coordinates" you can also try [this plugin to gdal](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) which makes it a bit easier to work with plain non-georeferenced maps in leaflet.

Comment: Although the image is a map of the U.S. (in Lambert Conformal projection), I don't think it is georeferenced.  How do I make it geo-referenced?  Alternatively, can I use tileLayer for non-georeferenced tiles?  Thanks again.

Comment: @kykong Do you want to visualize only your map or do you want to show additional "real" geodata like a map in the background and streets or railways as overlays on your map?

Comment: Yes, I basically just want to visualize my map in Leaflet.  It would be great if some geo-referencing capability (such as the latitude/longitude) is available but I can go without it.

Comment: Alright, I added a solution for both ways to my answer.